# Get a place ID on tap Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I built in google maps into my app.
If you zoom close enough you will see places (see screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYCWl.png

I need to get the place ID for those places (ie when a user taps on it), thought this would be straightforward but unfortunately I cannot find it.

It would be similar as the official google maps app, if you click a place, it will load all the place information.

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

i will come straight to the point . follow the steps as i say.

first on the [onMapClickListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener) you will get the latlng and we will use this to get a place id for that place.

use this url to get the place id . the url will return json data and you can check it on browser that this gives a place id for that place. then you have to parse it in your app accordingly . the url is as follows-

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=your_latitude,your_longitude&sensor=false&key=your_api_key

give it a try and let me know.

thank you

Comment: Can you please accept this as correct answer if it is what you needed.

Comment: This would be a good 2nd solution, unfortunately, I only want to tap these places and not everything. They are there so it seems weird that you can't tap them and get info about them. I will continue searching how to fix this, if not then your answer will be the best solution to my problem and I will mark as a correct answer!

Comment: you can ask me if you dont get what you want . please clarify the case. i will be happy to help .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PlacePicker.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker